# Is it possible to serve static files from outside the wwwroot folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 6 project with the following structure:

```
project/
  wwwroot/
  custom/
  project.json
```

I want to serve files from `custom` as it if was a virtual folder into `http://localhost/custom` without having to copy them during development.

Is it possible to do this in vNext without a virtual folder from IIS (say, using the StaticFile middleware)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the file provider on the options object when using the middleware.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\Path\To\Files"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/somepath")
})
```

See:
https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/Infrastructure/SharedOptions.cs#L44

and

https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical/PhysicalFileProvider.cs

Comment: You might want to create a `composite` file provider which looks at both the `web root` folder and also your custom folder. Currently there is no built-in composite provider but its easy to create one.

Comment: Keep in mind that the application would fail to start if the directory does not exist. This had me stumped on a deployment to test server for a little bit.

Comment: Is it possible to preserve the path? e.g. http://localhost/somepath redirects to http://localhost. How can I let it stay on /somepath?

Comment: Would this translate well to Linux file paths?