# Is it possible to serve Favicon from the root folder in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, favicon, static-content

In ASP.NET Core MVC these ways are possible to serve Favicon:

1. Place favicon in wwwroot and then serve it using `/favicon` path
2. Place it in a custom folder, and then use `PhysicalFileProvider` to configure delivering static files with special patterns from that folder

However, the third way, which by the way is the old way, is to put Favicon in the root folder of the project, and serve it from there.

I need the third option because we're using a Software Production Line, that has its rules.

So, is it possible?

Update: Some point me to the old questions regarding ASP.NET MVC. For those people, ASP.NET Core MVC serves static contents differently and these two technologies are not the same. Anything static in ASP.NET MVC would be served as simple as pointing to it in URL. In ASP.NET Core MVC things are different.

Comment: @GSerg, what does `UseStaticFiles` have to do with the post you linked to? `IgnoreRoute` doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core, so that doesn't apply. He's asking about the _project_ folder, not the _site_ folder, which is what you get with `UseStaticFiles`.

Comment: @McGuireV10 Yes, I misread about the project folder. In which case it is a possible duplicate of [Is it possible to serve static files from outside the wwwroot folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31946949/11683).

Comment: Yeah it does look like a dupe of that second one. Although I'd use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` instead of a hard-coded path like that answer suggests.

Comment: No, this is not the duplicate of the second mention question. That question refers to **outside** of the *site* folder, or `wwwroot` folder, which turns out to be yet another folder. My question is very specific about **the root of project, just sibling to Program.cs and Startup.cs**.

Comment: Your code does not run from your project folder. It runs from a server where it is deployed, and your project structure is not there anymore. If you place `favicon.ico` in the root folder of the project, it will be ignored by default. If you set its `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`, it will be copied into the root folder of the deployed website, just outside the `wwwroot` folder. You can then use the `StaticFileOptions` and target that location with `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` like @McGuire suggests.

Comment: @GSerg, did what you said and it doesn't work. Returns 404.

Comment: Well, it works for me... that is, for certain definitions of "works." If you kept the `RequestPath = new PathString("/somepath")`, you need to query for `/somepath/favicon.ico`, then it does return it. Alternatively, you could omit setting `RequestPath` altogether, then it would return it under the usual path. The problem is that it would then also return other static files in the root folder, including the json files with your passwords (and that it stops serving the normal static files from `wwwroot`, but that is already mentioned in that question).

Comment: If you're adamant you need to store your icon among these sensitive files (and not just e.g. create a symlink for `favicon.ico` in your project to keep the external tools are happy), you should implement `IFileProvider` from scratch that only serves this single file, and register it for static files alongside with `env.WebRootFileProvider` in a composite provider (`app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() { FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(env.WebRootFileProvider, new FaviconContentProvider()) });`).

Comment: "I need the third option because we're using a Software Production Line, that has its rules." - What are the rules?