# Tusdotnet Upload and Download Files .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

**Tusdotnet** is built for File uploads with .NET core Implementations, which are larger in size (*If in case its gets stuck it will be resume from the same point*).

- ASP .NET Core Implementation for uploading File:

  ```html
  app.UseTus(httpContext => new DefaultTusConfiguration
  {
      // c:\tusfiles is where to store files
      Store = new TusDiskStore(@"C:\tusfiles\"),
      // On what url should we listen for uploads?
      UrlPath = "/files",
      Events = new Events
      {
          //OnFileCompleteAsync = eventContext =>
          OnFileCompleteAsync = async eventContext =>
          {

              //return Task.CompletedTask;
              ITusFile file = await eventContext.GetFileAsync();          
              if (file != null)
              {
                  //Convert in to a FileStream
                  //var fileStream = await file.GetContentAsync(httpContext.RequestAborted);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet

- After upload in folder system:
  [image]

I need to ask that:

- For download the file we need to write a custom code but how it will be possible to identify the **file extension** at that level.
- And what technique we need to use for download File, as Tusdotnet said we are not responsible for downloading the file.

Comment: `And what technique we need to use for download File, as Tusdotnet said we are not responsible for downloading the file` Where are you storing the files?

Comment: `For download the file we need to write a custom code but how it will be possible to identify the file extension at that level.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886866/how-to-find-the-extension-of-a-file-in-c

Comment: For uploading files we are using the above code: Reference: https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet

Comment: Where are you **storing** the files? Is it C:\tusfiles\? If so, does `app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
    FileProvider =  new PhysicalFileProvider("c:\tusfiles\"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/tusfiles")
});` work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31948829/34092

Comment: In terms of filename, check out https://tus.io/faq.html (`How can I get the file name or file type for an upload?`)

Comment: Downloads are not handled by tusdotnet. the above link is not useful for me.
Reference:https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet/issues/82

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946949/is-it-possible-to-serve-static-files-from-outside-the-wwwroot-folder/31948829#31948829

Comment: @mjwills, yes I tried your suggestion, Its working only for case **Point 2**, for **Point 1** its coming without extension so its not working..
1) URL/files/c06d3d1d9ccd414f8306367cb50b69a7
2) URL/files/test2.jpg

Comment: Did you read my other two links? One for how to pass up the filename in metadata, and one how to get the file extension from a filename?

Comment: Yes, passing File Name in meta data, I am passing it upon uploading of document.

Comment: Awesome - so use the metadata to rename it once it is uploaded.

Comment: You can refer that link, I am using the same for upload

https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet/blob/master/Source/TestSites/AspNetCore_netcoreapp3.1_TestApp/wwwroot/index.html#L90


The only issue is that if files are saving without format in folder structure as in above attached image, ** then how we will be able to download it from there **

Comment: Did you perhaps consider renaming the files after they finished uploading?

Comment: Total (05) files has been uploaded with a single upload attachment. I have checked rest of them as well, they are attached in image file.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the files after they finished uploading?

Comment: yes If I tried to changes the extension after uploading, its work in that case, but I don't think like its a good practice..

Comment: Why is it not good practice?

Comment: Its mean we need to rename file when its upload successfully by custom code.

Comment: Awesome - and why is that bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating with Tusdotnet I found only two options:

> First Approach

Renaming of file when the file is successfully uploaded in the folder system. (As tusdotnet not maintain file extension when its upload successfully.
[image]

> Second Approach

Parallelly when tusdotnet upload your file successfully, upload same file with extension as well by using below code:

```
OnFileCompleteAsync = async eventContext =>
{    
    ITusFile file = await eventContext.GetFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        var fileStream = await file.GetContentAsync(httpContext.RequestAborted);
        var metadata = await file.GetMetadataAsync(httpContext.RequestAborted);
    
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = metadata.ContainsKey("contentType")
                                         ? metadata["contentType"].GetString(Encoding.UTF8)
                                         : "application/octet-stream";
    
        //Providing New File name with extension
        string name = "NewFileName.jpg";
        string networkPath = @"C:\tusfiles\";
    
        using (var fileStream2 = new FileStream(networkPath + "\\" + name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream2);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

[image]